# How to convert dates to valid format in Google Data Studio?

Tags: data-science, looker-studio

I have a google sheet with dates in europian format ( 15.09.2020 08:40 ) . When importing the sheet to data studio it detects this field as text. I try to change it to DATE but get error "Cant convert". Maybe becouse its in european format? Anyone know how to change this? I have tried formatting in google sheets with no luck...

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert it yourself, with the european date as as string in the field `your_field`, create an additional field with following formula:

```
PARSE_DATETIME("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", your_field)
```

The details for date converting/parsing can be found here:
https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9739558